# White screen showing long time in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing native ionic application for Android platform. When I open my app, there is a white screen showing for long time and entered into the page. I don't want to show the white screen or is there any way to reduce the white screen showing time.  I am new to Ionic. Please suggest me on this point.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the config.xml:

```
 <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" /> // You can control how many seconds the splash screen will be displayed
 <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
 <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
 <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
 <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
 <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

and then on the `platform.ready()` call `Splashscreen.hide();`

Answer (score 0):

In config.xml file please increase follow preference value.

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code. It might be related to not using lazy loading correctly.
If you are importing your pages into your app module, or while navigating you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your main.ts file from

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**To**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";

enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

If you are running your app with production flag(--prod).

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy loading to minimize white screen time.